# Unable to fill text field in nested div via page object model

Tags: rspec, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a text field on an overlay. I have declared this text field in my page file as below.

```
div(:simple_query_elements, :class => "widgetContainer")
text_field(:simple_query_value) { simple_query_elements_element.div_element(:id => /xwt_widget_notification_ValidationTextBox_/) }
```

I am trying to fill the text box as below.

```
self.simple_query_value = "Device Name"
```

In this try I am facing the below error

> ```
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `value=' for #<Watir::Div:0x404b620>
> ```

But while I am trying to fill the text box using Watir API, I am able to fill the text field  without any issues. I mean the below snippet works good.

```
@browser.div(:class => "widgetContainer").text_field(:id => /xwt_widget_notification_ValidationTextBox_/).set "Device Name"
```

Please provide some resolution to achieve it by using page object model .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the problem is just a typo in the definition of the `:simple_query_value`. Notice that it says `simple_query_elements_element.div_element`. As seen in the pure Watir code, you want a text field not a div. In other words, it should be `simple_query_elements_element.text_field_element`.

Comment: @JustinKo, ou should put that in as an answer

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden, I can add it as a community answer. Given that it is a simple typographical error, I believe the correct response is really to be voting to close the question (which I did).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is just a typo in the definition of the `:simple_query_value`.

Notice that it says:

```
simple_query_elements_element.div_element
```

As seen in the pure Watir code, you want a text field not a div. In other words, it should be:

```
simple_query_elements_element.text_field_element
```